# Adding textfile string into specific list item

Tags: c#

I have a text file that has a string like:
"•5•Enter Title Name•Enter Description Here•30/04/2015•UNFINISHED•"

I am reading this text file in, how can I write it so the items between the • are put in seperate variables or strings. I have a general idea, using foreach loops with an if statement that checks for the specific character. Can anybody help me please? (code so far is below)

```
MessageBox.Show("Opening saved file: TaskFile.txt");
            string path1 = (@"TaskFile.txt");
            string lineOfText = File.ReadAllText(path1);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(lineOfText);



            foreach (var sItem in lineOfText)
            {
                 if(sItem == '•')
                 {
                     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("test");


                 }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Split method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) and use it like this

```
List<string> list = sItem.Split('.').ToList();
```

Comment: Nice and simple, unfortunately we tend to over-engineer things when we don't fully understand the capability of the language.

Comment: @Ehsan should the split method not be applied on lineOfText  ? lineOfText .split('.') ?

Comment: Ideally he should be doing ReadLines and then using the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ehsan on the Split method, but I think it should be like this:

```
var arrayOfStrings =  lineOfText.Split('•');

foreach (var str in arrayOfStrings)
{
   //do something.
}
```